# Add Dropbox SDK to my app already running Chooser API, and is live on store

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

My iOS app live on store has Chooser API and its working fine. Now I want to add dropbox Upload Feature from within app.

Given that there's no Saver API for iOS, I've to user DropboxSDK (Dropbox Core API), but my app on Dropbox App Console has permission type Drop-in, and dropboxSDK wants it to be either kDBRootDropbox or kDBAppFolder.

I want to use kDBAppFolder option, so that my app can upload files in AppFolder. But on Dropbox App Console there's no way to change it.

**Question:-**
How can I update permissions for my app on App Console?

Do I need to delete my existing app and create NEW app with proper permissions ? If so would this effect the DBChooser feature running in my app already with all those users out there ? Would it effect DBChooser feature in New Downloads from app store ?

Quick help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Cross-referencing with post on the Dropbox API forum: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/204021705-Add-Dropbox-SDK-to-my-app-already-running-Chooser-API-and-is-live-on-store-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a new app, but don't delete the old one. (Deleting the old one will break your existing app in the app store.)

Once you've created the new app with the right permission, you can switch to using the new app key everywhere in your app (in a future update).

Comment: Thank you @smarx. if I use `kDBAppFolder` for my New App, would I be able to pick / download files outside of my App Folder ? Because using chooser API I can pick a file from anywhere in my Dropbox. I can use the `kDBRootDropbox ` but I would like all my uploads go into one particular folder. Which of the 2 permissions is my best choice ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can still use the Chooser to get files from anywhere. It sounds like app folder permission is right for you.

Comment: I've updated my project with New API Key (from new app I created on Dropbox App Console) and secret, but now my Chooser API is causing a conflict with Newly added Core API at URL Types in info.plist.

If I remove the Chooser app's key, I can upload just fine. If I keep it I get this error:
DBChooser dbc_appKeyFromInfoPlist Assertion failuire

I checked DBChooser.m on git and its fetching AppKey like this:
appKey = [scheme substringFromIndex:3]; // substring after "db-"

which explains the error.
Any suggestion on how to make them both work together ??

Comment: Just use the new app key. It should work for both the Core API and the Chooser.